# How to choose a specific branch and merge before clone in git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

I have a repo online, that I no longer make use of the master branch, so I created a branch called `dev-test` and pushed all my local repo to this branch, but now in my VPS, I installed git and need the `dev-test` branch. So, I have been trying a lot to only get this branch but it seems a little bit complicated than that.

It seems there is no way to choose a specific branch unless you download the master first.

I did `git clone https://foo@bitbucket.org/foo/repo.name.git`

this clones the `repo.name` source, but only the master branch. Then I tried to change the branch to `git checkout -b dev-test` and did `git fetch dev-test` but this does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove your local branch (which is not tracking the origin/dev-test here) and try with `git checkout dev-test`

Comment: @fpietka How do I remove it?, You mean delete the entire `repo.name` folder? Than I would have to initialiaze git otherwise, git won't work

Comment: Just do `git branch -d dev-test`. I think you really should take a look at the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en) to understand a bit more about Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without extra options, `git clone` clones the entire repository.  This includes copying all of its branch labels, but they get renamed, because you might or might not want their branch names to match yours, or—more likely—you may only want to keep up with one or two of "their" branches.

Once that is done, as the very last step, `git clone` does a `git checkout` to put you on the branch you select.  Which branch is that?  The answer is: "it depends", but usually, if you don't select a branch on the `clone` command, you are telling git to check out branch `master`.

You can simply `git checkout dev-test` at that point to switch to another branch; or you can pass `-b dev-test` to `git clone` to tell it "check out `dev-test`, not whatever the default would be".  In either case, git will look at the branch-labels it cloned from the remote (in the `git clone` step) and make new, local branch labels that "track" the "remote-tracking branches".  You can see local branches with `git branch` and "remote branches" with `git branch -r` (or both at the same time with `git branch -a`).  See more about this below.

The `git fetch` command does not take branch names, but rather the names of remotes.  The default remote is named `origin`, and this refers to the repository from which you did your `git clone`.  Using `git fetch` (or `git fetch origin`), you tell your git to call up the same remote site you used on your original `git clone`, tell it what you have now, and ask it to send you anything new since then.

---

As fpietka noted in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058406/how-to-choose-a-specific-branch-and-merge-before-clone-in-git#comment38980423_25058406) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058406/how-to-choose-a-specific-branch-and-merge-before-clone-in-git#comment38981014_25058406), you need to change (or rebuild) your mental model of what git is doing.  Using `git checkout` *without* `-b`, you ask git to find an existing branch:

```
git checkout zorg
```

This looks first for local branch `zorg`, and if it exists, tries to switch to it.  If local branch `zorg` does not exist, it will check for remote `origin/zorg`.  If *that* exists, git will *create* local branch `zorg`, pointing to the same commit as remote-tracking-branch `origin/zorg`.

Often, you will want to create a new local branch that does not, and maybe never will, exist on the remote at all.  (For instance, if you want to experiment with some changes, but don't intend for them to be "production quality", you can just create some local-experiment branches.)  To create a new branch that will grow from whatever commit you're now on, *this* is when you use `git checkout -b`:

```
git checkout -b experiment-1
```

Now new commits will grow a new (local-only) branch named `experiment-1`.

Whenever you do a `git commit`, git:

1. looks to see what branch you're on (`git status` tells you, and `git branch` marks this one with an asterisk `*`)
2. uses the current "index" or "staging area" (see `git add`) to decide what should be in this new commit
3. creates a new commit, with a commit message you specify (usually by running your editor, or from the `-m` argument, or whatever) with the current date and time and your name from your git configuration data, and last
4. takes the big ugly SHA-1 that names the actual commit—these are the `commit f5f7ce02e16cf4fc038be2f04ac44623a7c2523c` things that show up in `git log`—and stores that SHA-1 ID in the "current branch", the one you're on from step 1.

It's that last step that makes the current branch grow (and hence move forward).

If you're on your `dev-test` branch, your `dev-test` grows a new commit each time you make changes and then `git add` and `git commit` them.

---

All of this activity occurs only in *your* repository, not in anyone else's.  Meanwhile, if you cloned someone else's repository, there's a good chance they (whoever they are) are doing their own activity and making *their* local branches—which are your "remote" branches, in `origin/`—move forward.  You (and your git) have no way of knowing if and when they do stuff.  All you can do is ask, at some point, "Hmm ... I wonder what they have been doing?"

This is when you run `git fetch`.  *Your* git calls up *their* git and says: "hey, I copied branch `dev-test` from you, and last I knew it was `f5f7ce02e16cf4fc038be2f04ac44623a7c2523c`, what is it now?"  Their git says what it is now, and your git and their git figure out what they have done since then.  Your git brings over all those changes—but it does not, and *should* not, change *your* `dev-test`.  You might have been doing a bunch of stuff in there!

So, *your* git updates your `origin/dev-test` according to what *their* git has in *their* `dev-test`.  This is the way git handles branch naming across cloned repositories.

At this point, if you have done work *and* they have done work, you will presumably want to merge or rebase your work to incorporate theirs, or convince them to do the same.  But that's another topic, for later (or the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en)).